# Make sidebars resizeable on drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

OK, so I've built a basic test template with a fluid center content section, and 2 fixed-width sidebars (one on the left, and one the right).

So, my question is :

Is it possible to make this two sidebars resizeable by the user? (e.g. like a split pane)

Any ideas?

---

**Demo:** `http://83.212.101.132/angjs/ang4.html`

Comment: ansewr to your question, is this possible or not, the answer if yes it is possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can using jquery UI:

http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/

The code is pretty simple:

```
$( ".Class Name" ).resizable({ aspectRatio: true  });
```

Comment: Hmm... Just tried it like `$("aside").resizable({ aspectRatio: true  });` ("aside" being the two sidebars), but nothing happened. Any ideas?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

You need to include the css and also jquery to use jquery ui

Comment: Boy! I can't believe I missed including the jQuery UI CSS (i had it in, for another test of mine, but it looks like I forgot about it this time). Thanks a lot! Very smooth solution. And it works great! :-)